# Highcharts spline-symbols with right aligned lines

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to align all lines in a highchart Spline with symbols to the right.

Lets imagine you have a smaller dataset for one series, something similar to the image below:

[image: highchart spline]

What I need is to align all lines (in this case, the blue one) to the right side without modifing the dataset, just with CSS or JS or any highchart configuration.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution to keep the same proportions of the second series will be using multiple axis and set [spline.xAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.xAxis) which axis is connected.

```js
let data1 = [3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 13.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 13.2],
  data2 = [2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 2, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },

  xAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data1'
    },
    alignTicks: false
  }, {
    alignTicks: false,
    opposite: true
  }],

  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data1'
    }
  }, {
    opposite: true
  }],

  series: [{
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    data: data1
  }, {
    data: data2
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/16vaqm2g/

Comment: I can work with that. Could you please update your code showing how it would be if I have 5 datasets? Thank you

Comment: Easily [yAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis) can be added as a new object that creates array of configurable axis multiple objects. You can change the params axis, in this case, [yAxis.visible](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.visible) set to false hidden axis that you don't want to show.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/16vaqm2g/1/